# Getting certain list items in Applescript

Tags: arrays, list, applescript

So I have a little script that should add the first and the second item of a list/array in applescript. The code below compiles fine, but doesn't run. The error it returns is as following: `«script» doesn’t understand the “theArray” message.` The error message that comes with it is -1708 which, according to https://www.osstatus.com, means `errAEEventNotHandled`.

```
set theArray to {1, 2}
set theSolution to theArray(1) + theArray(2)
```

Comment: **AppleScript** doesn't use the term _array_. It uses [**`list`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE), even though it is analigious to an _indexed array_, as in some other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theArray(1)` is wrong syntax. To get an item of an array you have to write `item 1 of theArray` or `first item of theArray`

```
set theArray to {1, 2}
set theSolution to item 1 of theArray + item 2 of theArray
```